# Swift 2 : Sound on NSTimer Always Plays Twice

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

So I've got an NSTimer running a function every 0.1 seconds.

No matter how many conditions & caveats I put in place, this sound (and others on the timer) play twice. The same sound triggered by a touch plays only once.

```
myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("flip:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Here's the function it triggers.

```
func flip(timer: NSTimer) {

    if current_timer == -3.0 && rang_3 == false {

            if rang_3 == false {

                rang_3 = true

                dialed_3()

                NSLog("DIALED 3")
            }

    }

}
```

And here's the sound function I need triggered only ONCE.

```
func dialed_3() {

    if sound_mute == false {

        do {

            dial_3 =  try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("3", ofType: "mp3")!))
            dial_3.volume = 2
            dial_3.numberOfLoops = 0
            dial_3.prepareToPlay()
            dial_3.play()


        } catch {

            print("Error")

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Your code is silly. First, you are saying `if current_timer == -3.0 && rang_3 == false { if rang_3 == false {`. You already established that `rang_3` is false, so why are you asking twice? Second, never never never compare a Bool to `false` or `true`; it is already a Bool. Thus, this should be expressed `if current_timer == -3.0 && !rang_3`.

Comment: Also, please show more code; what are you doing, if anything, to prevent `current_timer` from being `-3.0` more than once? Also please tell us what the logging shows. Are you hearing the sound twice but seeing the log message once, or what?

Comment: Another point: presumably you have just one `dial_3` property, and presumably it is an Optional. So why not start `dialed_3` by asking whether it is non-`nil`? If it is, you've done this already, so `return` without doing anything more.

Comment: My code is silly because one Bool check/switch wasn't working – so I put them everywhere I could. Thanks for the Bool tip!

Comment: The currenttimer is increased by 0.1 every time the timer ticks (0.1seconds).  Sound plays twice & the Log prints twice as well.

Comment: The { && !rang_3 } change didn't fix it – I was hoping that was it. But thanks again for that tip. I'm 100% youtube/google/stack learned.

Comment: No, I didn't think it would. But it is silly to show silly code. :) I made many other suggestions, plus you should show more code. No one can reproduce the problem based on what you have said so far.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your other code, but with what you show, it runs 1 time. 
A small suggestion for you: move initialization to global without run it everytime timer run.

Answer (score 0):

Alright! So I moved the `!rang_3` check to the fixed `!sound_mute` check & it worked. As a failsafe I replicated the sounds that are used during countdown & muted them after 1 play. So if they play twice, the user won't notice.

```
if !sound_mute && !rang_3 {

    do {

        //soundstuff

    }

}
```